# NSPersistentDocument App Delegate

Tags: cocoa

I  just created a new Core Data Document application, and in the template provided (there's only the NSPersistentDocument subclass and model), I want to stick

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed:(NSApplication *)theApplication
    return YES;
}
```

somewhere... where do I put it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode's document-based app template does not include an AppDelegate class by default. You have to create it manually (by subclassing NSObject), add it to your MainMenu.xib and drag a connection from the "delegate" outlet of Application to your new AppDelegate object.